# Hibernate cannot make distinction between columns with the same name

Tags: java, mysql, sql, hibernate

I have a table called cinema with a column ipaddress.

I have a table called tms with a column ipaddress.

When I perform the query specified below, the t.ipaddress returns the value of c.ipaddress. What do I have to do to solve this problem?

```
        sqlStatement1 = 
                  "select c.IpAddress,        "
                + "       c.User,             "
                + "       c.Password,         "
                + "       c.connectionType,   "
                + "       c.NominalBandwidth, "
                + "       t.ipaddress ,       "
                + "       t.user,             "
                + "       t.password,         "
                + "       t.direction,        "
                + "       t.ftp_script,       "
                + "       t.bandwidth,        "
                + "       t.tmsId,             " 
                + "       d.assetFilePath,     " 
                + "       bt.status     "
                + "from   "
                + ConfigurationParametersHelper.getInstance()
                        .getConfValidated("DBASE_SCHEMA")
                + ".booking b,     "
                + "       "
                + ConfigurationParametersHelper.getInstance()
                        .getConfValidated("DBASE_SCHEMA")
                + ".bookingtms bt, "
                + "       "
                + ConfigurationParametersHelper.getInstance()
                        .getConfValidated("DBASE_SCHEMA")
                + ".dcp d,         "
                + "       "
                + ConfigurationParametersHelper.getInstance()
                        .getConfValidated("DBASE_SCHEMA")
                + ".cinema c,      "
                + "       "
                + ConfigurationParametersHelper.getInstance()
                        .getConfValidated("DBASE_SCHEMA")
                + ".tms t          "
                + "where  b.IdKey          = "
                + booking.getIdKey()
                + " "
                + "and    bt.booking_IdKey = b.IdKey "
                + "and    b.dcp_id         = d.id "
                + "and    c.Id             = b.cinema_Id "
                + "and    t.cinema_id      = c.Id "
                + "and    t.tmsid          = bt.tms_tmsid "
                + "order  by bt.id asc";
```

UPDATE1: if I specify t.ipaddress before c.ipaddress in the query, c.ipaddress gets overwritten by the t.ipaddress and vice versa.

Comment: You need to add an alias to the projection

Comment: Thx geoand, could you elaborate a little bit on that?

Answer (score 1):

Here is just a small relevant part of an example of rewriting the query

```
          "select c.IpAddress cIpAddress,        "
        + "       c.User,             "
        + "       c.Password,         "
        + "       c.connectionType,   "
        + "       c.NominalBandwidth, "
        + "       t.ipaddress tIpAddress,       "
        + "       t.user,             "
        + "       t.password,         "
        + "       t.direction,        "
        + "       t.ftp_script,       "
        + "       t.bandwidth,        "
        + "       t.tmsId,             " 
        + "       d.assetFilePath,     " 
        + "       bt.status     "
        + "from   "
```

Note the aliases `cIpAddress`, `tIpAddress`

Comment: I get the following message:

2014-04-25 09:53:38 INFO  StringType:205 - could not read column value from result set: IpAddress; Column 'IpAddress' not found.
2014-04-25 09:53:38 WARN  JDBCExceptionReporter:100 - SQL Error: 0, SQLState: S0022
2014-04-25 09:53:38 ERROR JDBCExceptionReporter:101 - Column 'IpAddress' not found.

They are defined as string in pojo class and as varchar in DB. They have to be unique

Comment: You need to be reading cIpAddress and tIpAddress from the `resultSet` instead of IpAddress